# What is an idiom to describe someone who takes sides with both of two opposing sides?

Tags: adjectives, idiom-requests

What is an idiom (or an adjective) to describe someone who considers and takes sides with both of two opposing sides?

I mean someone who, for example, says that both of contrasting sides in an argument could be right.

Comment: Too many contexts.  Is this person disinterested? Interested but hiding the interest? Duplicitous? Staying neutral or going a third way? There's a lot of room between "undecided" and "playing both sides against the middle."

Comment: Bothsidesism, false equivalence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a foot in both camps**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+foot+in+both+camps) This idiom describes participation with both sides:

> some involvement with or support for two opposing sides.

As in:

- > When my friends split up, I felt like I had a foot in both camps.

Though it would not be idiomatic, the opposite would be grammatical:

- > When my friends split up, I felt like I had a foot in neither camp
  >   and had lost both as friends.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the idiom you're looking for is "sitting on the fence"? it is used to describe a person's lack of decisiveness, neutrality or hesitance to choose between two sides in an argument or a competition, or inability to decide due to lack of courage.

see more here: (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-sit-on-the-fence)

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Add a dictionary reference to enhance your answer, please.

Answer (score -1):

I found this, or rather Siri did, when asking for a word that describes this… sitting on the fence, or having a foot in both camps kinda game.

I was watching a viral video, and this guy was going on and on about how his worldview a few months ago was rocked because he started asking questions and seeing things and so on and so forth that he wasn’t aware of. But I found myself waiting for the punchline… Which side of the fence are you on friend, it was a long video and I found myself actually skipping forward. He never does come out and say which side he is on or what specifically rocked his world he gives no indication at all as to which side he is on and even goes on to reference a book whose title and author, he also fails to mention , I went on to view his other video posts, searching for a hint on which pill he swallowed red or blue. I scrolled back several months and found more of the same so he’s kind of the exact opposite of someone who’s got foot in both camps or is sitting on the fence.

In the end I felt manipulated. I was a little angry that this guy was playing a game with his viewers by appealing to both sides, and not defining either side that he was supporting … the things he was saying, and the way he was saying it could’ve applied to either side depending on your POV.

The end I wrote a poem about it, which is why I’m looking for the word I’m looking for. I’ll turn it into a song. I’ll share it with him.

Sitting on the fence … To me anyway means indecisiveness you could fall either way into either camp. A foot in both camps more accurately describes what the OP is looking for an idiom.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).